# Converting Windows 8.x Enterprise into Pro so I could activate it and use at home

Tags: windows-8, windows-activation

Is there any possibility to convert Windows 8 Enterprise to Pro edition so I could normally activate it?

I used Enterprise 90 trial version which has been expired.

Now I want to legally buy a license but this is an Enterprise edition, it's impossible to just buy it for a home PC.

On the other hand I don't want to buy CD and re-install a Pro version on top of current setup.

If I just get Pro CD and install it, would that overwrite all the installations I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the tool [UpDown8](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/36726-UpDown8-Windows-8-Upgrade-Downgrade-Helper), select the Windows 8 Pro. When you now run the Setup.exe of the Pro DVD from a running Windows and select ["Upgrade" (repair Install/Inplace Upgrade)](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html) the Enterprise Eval is downgraded to the Pro Edition.

[image]

Comment: Does/ does not the Enterprise license/ activation have to be removed? Or its automatic. 

What about license steps when doing reverse with UpDown from Pro to Enterprise.

Comment: Windows needs to be re-activated with a proper Licence key.